# How to convert jQuery code to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery:

```
var isResizing = false,
    lastDownX = 0;

$(function () {
    var container = $('#container'),
        top = $('#top-panel'),
        handle = $('#drag');

    handle.on('mousedown', function (e) {
        isResizing = true;
        lastDownX = e.clientY;
    });

    $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
        if (!isResizing) 
            return;
        var offsetRight = top.height() + (e.clientY - container.offset().top);

        top.css('top', offsetRight);
    }).on('mouseup', function (e) {
        // stop resizing
        isResizing = false;
    });
});
```

JavaScript:

```
var isResizing = false
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
var lastDownX = 0

function resizeVerticallyInit () {
  var top = document.querySelector('#topology-container')
  var handle = document.querySelector('#drag')

  handle.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    isResizing = true
    lastDownX = e.clientY
  })

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
    if (!isResizing) {
      return
    }
    var offsetRight = top.height() + 20

    document.querySelector('#topology-container').style.top = offsetRight
  })

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
    // stop resizing
    isResizing = false
  })
}

mounted () {
  ...
  resizeVerticallyInit()
}
```

As you can see I use JavaScript function in Vue.js component in mounted() life-cycle method.

I've tried to convert it, but it doesn't work.

First of all I needed to put:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
var lastDownX = 0
```

I don't know why it's complaining that lastDownX is unused.

The second one is error:

```
"[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"
```

It's complaining about:

```
  handle.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    isResizing = true
    lastDownX = e.clientY
  })
```

Could someone help to convert it?

Comment: Could you _at least_ post your code properly to begin with?

Comment: I've done all as usual, but it displays like that.

Comment: (Using 1), 2) creates numbered lists, inside those the normal four-space-indent for code does not appear to fully work. Fixed, by removing the numbers.)

Comment: I don’t see where you would even be _calling_ `resizeVerticallyInit` right now. But that is probably part of the problem - `$(function () {})` is jQuery syntax for firing this at document.ready - if you did nothing in your implementation, to make sure the function is called after that, then it probably doesn’t find the element, because it simply does not exist yet.

Comment: I use JavaScript function in Vue.js component in mounted().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of `document.querySelector` method will return `null` if the element is not present in DOM. You cannot call `addEventListener` on null. In `jQuery` it worked because jquery constructs a separate object (called jQuery object). A jQuery object looks somewhat like this:

```js
{
  0: {...} // HTMLElement reference
  length: 1
} // jQuery object
```

This object exposes a jQuery API which has `on` method for event handling (available regardless of presence of actual DOM element). This is a beauty of jQuery (and a drawback).

Query selector method on the other hand returns the `HTMLElement`. If the element is not present in DOM then `null` is returned.

Now assuming that the element will appear in DOM after certain amount of time, there are two things you can do:

1. Wait for element to be present in DOM, and once it is available, add a listener function.
2. Use `live` events (event delegation) in JavaScript.

I will show you the second approach:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML = `<button id="btn">Click</button>`;
}, 3000);

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.id === 'btn') {
    alert('Click works!');
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  A button will appear after 3 seconds. However, click event would still work.
</div>
```

As you can see I am using `e.target` to detect which element I clicked inside document (where I have attached the listener). Once the condition matches, it triggers the `alert`. This allows us to bind events for elements that are not initially present in DOM.